# jQuery Dialog with an async option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have written a JS event handler that is raised just before a control uploads a file. In my event handler, i have the choice to cancel the upload and that choice depends on whether what options the user selects. I have written the event handler to show a jQuery Dialog box, asking the user if they want to cancel the upload.

Problem: jQuery Dialog works in an async fashion. Therefore, by the time the user selects the option to either go with the upload or cancel it, the event handler would have already finished executing with no chance of specifying whether or not to cancel or allow the upload.

Can I run jQuery Dialog run synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

The upload operation should not be started until the dialog box is confirmed or canceled. Take a look [here](http://www.jensbits.com/2009/08/10/modal-confirmation-dialog-on-form-submit-javascript-jquery-ui-and-thickbox-varieties/) for an example.